# Clean Data of an Android App

Tags: applications

Sometimes we need to do Clean Data for an android app.

And to do Clean Data of a specific app, we need to in that app. For cleaning data of more apps, we need to go all apps individually.

Is there any way so that I can do Clean Data on one page/ place for all installed apps?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do it through the Settings - Apps menu, however  you can do it via an adb shell with

`adb shell pm clear packageName`

Where `packageName` is the name of the actual package (not the application), such as `com.android.browser` for the built in Browser app.

Shouldn't be too hard to create a script to do this for multiple applications.

Comment: Do you mean to say, I can create a script one time for all required apps. And just after running a single script, Clean Data will be processed for all required apps? Will that work on all android platform, irrespective of hardware specifications and android version? And does it require root access for its execution?

Comment: It should... you would create a Windows/Linux script to send each line individually, this would be run from a computer and NOT from the device. I would say it would work with Android 4.x and up that has ADB Debugging enabled and you have the proper drivers installed on the PC.